# Different behavior of android.app.Fragment and android.support.v4.app.Fragment while using backstack

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've created Activity and added a fragment to it using `FragmentManeger`. When i use `android.app.Fragment` and press the back button my application closes. When i use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and press the back button, the fragment is removed from the activity, but application is still working. I can't really understand why is that happening.

Here is the code i used:

Activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_fragment, new Fragment1())
            .addToBackStack("first")
            .commit();
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public Fragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
    }
}
```

When i simply replace import in `Activity` and `Fragment` to same classes, but in the support library, the result is different...

EDIT:
I also replaced `getFragemetManeger()` to `getSupportFragmentMeneger()` and it still works different

Comment: Make sure you're using `getSupportFragmentManager()` for the support library

Comment: yes, i do. It's not the cause

Comment: I think that the behavior of support Fragment is correct and want to understand how to make android.app.Fragment behave the same way..

Comment: Like @ElliotM said, you need to change getFragmentManager() with getSupportFragmentManager().

Fragments and support fragments aren't interchangeable at all. Same goes with fragment managers.

Comment: does activity_main layout contain fragment? or content_fragment is just a placeholder?

Comment: @Daniil, rereading your post, looks like the solution would be to create a blank fragment. on start. Or even override your OnBack behavior to do something different when your backstack is empty.

Comment: @ BooleanCheese when i changed import i also changed getFragmentManager() to getSupportFragmentManager() otherwise it wouldn't compile

Comment: @Daniil I only bring the fragmentmanager thing because your example showed otherwise.

I really wouldn't be surprised if the support fragment manager behaved differently to avoid empty fragments on older versions.

Comment: @Selvin content_maneger is the id of FrameLayout in activity_main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occured because i used android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity and android.app.Fragment. I should've used   android.app.Fragment with android.app.Activity or AppCompatActivity with support fragment.

Answer (score 0):

if you're only looking to change the back behavior, you can try overriding 
onBackPressed with something like:

```
if(backstackCount() > 0)
{
     super.onBackPressed
}
```